# How to use 1 Java class for multiple imports from Firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, parcelable

You can see a draft of my Firebase DB structure below. As you can see I have the same fields (days of the week) in several subgroups (915d, 915e etc.). DB is created only for reading, writing from the app is not planned.

Is it possible to use 1 class for each day of the week to display the data according to the "Group" choosen? My idea was to customize the intent somehow and pass with it the DB reference, is that possible?

Can I use Parcelable interface for it?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Screen of Firebase Database

[image]

Comment: Do you have the same type of data under each day?

Comment: @Rohit I'll have Strings all over there. This integers on screenshot are just for testing purposes.